# implement generics in go using interfaces?

Tags: go, interface

I am trying to write a stack in Go which works for int and rune array type. But this does not seem to work. I thought that was supposed to work as I have an Interface type to hold any type. The operation of the stack is common for all types. I don't want to use the stack interface that comes with go

```golang
package main

import "math"

type expressionStack interface {
    pop() interface
    getSize() int
    push(item interface)
    peek() interface

}

type intStack []int
type runeStack []rune

func createStack(st interface) {
    return &expressionStack{}
}

func (stack *expressionStack) getSize() int {
    return len(stack)
}

func (stack *expressionStack) pop() int {
    length := len(stack)
    if length == 0 {
        panic("Stack is underflown")
    }
    item := stack[length-1]
    stack = stack[:length-1]
    return item
}

func (stack *expressionStack) push(item interface) {
    stack = append(stack, item)
}

func (stack *expressionStack) peek() int {
    leng := len(stack)
    if leng == 0 {
        return -math.MaxInt32
    }
    item := stack[leng-1]
    return item
}
```

Comment: Go does not allow for declaring methods on interfaces, or pointers to interfaces, so stuff like `func (stack *expressionStack) getSize() int {` where expressionStack if an interface type will not compile. There are other syntactical problems with the code, like the misuse of the `interface` keyword, you should probably take the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) or read the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec) to get the basics down first.

Comment: Maybe you know, maybe you don't, but Go proper does not support generics at the moment, they are scheduled to be added in Go 1.18 to be released in early 2022.

Comment: As @mkopriva pointed out, generics will be added to the language in February 2022. Can you not wait until then? How many specialisations (types of stack element) do you need anyway?

Comment: Not to mention that `peek` and `pop` should preferably return `(int, bool)` rather than return an `int` and potentially panic.

Comment: Here is a preview of what generics will allow you to do: https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/7l5FhD_oY-B

Answer (score 0):

a solution to those problem is to use code gen.

It requires to arrange a bit the api because generator are pretty dumb, but it does the job.

I start by declaring a package under GOPATH (old school) at `test/d/gen`

I create a new file `template.go`, and arranged a bit the code

```golang
package gen

type T int

type expressionStack []T

func (stack *expressionStack) getSize() int {
    return len(*stack)
}

func (stack *expressionStack) pop() T {
    length := len(*stack)
    if length == 0 {
        panic("Stack is underflown")
    }
    item := (*stack)[length-1]
    *stack = (*stack)[:length-1]
    return item
}

func (stack *expressionStack) push(item T) {
    *stack = append(*stack, item)
}

func (stack *expressionStack) peek() (zero T, ok bool) {
    leng := len(*stack)

    if leng == 0 {
        return
    }

    item := (*stack)[leng-1]
    return item, true
}
```

I have tried to use https://github.com/mmatczuk/go_generics witth something like `go_generics -t=T=int32 -t=expressionStack=IntStack -i=./template.go -o out.go -p gen`, but it failed.

tried another one https://github.com/clementauger/jenjen with `jenjen -template=test/d/gen "expressionStack:T => int32, T => -, expressionStack=>Int32Stack" -`

I got a neat output

```golang
package gen

type Int32Stack []int32

func (stack *Int32Stack) getSize() int {
    return len(*stack)
}

func (stack *Int32Stack) pop() int32 {
    length := len(*stack)
    if length == 0 {
        panic("Stack is underflown")
    }
    item := (*stack)[length-1]
    *stack = (*stack)[:length-1]
    return item
}

func (stack *Int32Stack) push(item int32) {
    *stack = append(*stack, item)
}

func (stack *Int32Stack) peek() (zero int32, ok bool) {
    leng := len(*stack)

    if leng == 0 {
        return
    }

    item := (*stack)[leng-1]
    return item, true
}
```

the hard stuff was to figure out that `"expressionStack:T => int32, T => -, expressionStack=>Int32Stack"`, its a three statements instructions,

- `expressionStack: T=>int32` within `expressionStack` replace `T` by `int32`
- `T => -`, within the package, remove `T`
- `expressionStack=>Int32Stack`, within the package, rename `expressionStack` to `Int32Stack`

Though, i had some problem saving the output to the desired file with that last package. not perfect.

there is also a bunch of others package to do that,

- https://github.com/cheekybits/genny
- https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/gofmt with -r option

Answer (score -2):

I think i found a solution

```
package main

import (
    "math"
    "reflect"
)

type expressionStack []interface{}

func (stack *expressionStack) getSize() int {
    return len(*stack)
}

func (stack *expressionStack) pop() interface{} {
    length := len(*stack)
    if length == 0 {
        panic("Stack is underflown")
    }
    item := (*stack)[length-1]
    *stack = (*stack)[:length-1]
    return item
}

func (stack *expressionStack) push(item interface{}) {
    *stack = append(*stack, item)
}

func (stack *expressionStack) peek() interface{} {
    leng := len(*stack)

    if reflect.TypeOf(stack).Kind() == reflect.Int32 {
        if leng == 0 {
            return -math.MaxInt32
        }
    } else {
        if leng == 0 {
            return 'E'
        }
    }

    item := (*stack)[leng-1]
    return item
}
```

Comment: You were right I read a spec . The reason I need to reflect.TypeOf(stack).Kind() == reflect.Int32  in peek method because I do some post processing for a rune &  a int stack differently

Comment: `reflect.TypeOf(stack).Kind() == reflect.Int32` unlikely it ever evaluates to true.

Comment: @mh-cbon, why do you say so, it evaluates to true whenever the stack holds integers and false when it holds rune type

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/qMXwTTfValu what makes you think differently ?